# findall and regular expressions, getting the correct pattern

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, findall

I'm working out of Magnus Lie Hetland's book, "Beginning Python" 2nd edition, and on page 244 he says the first pattern listed in my code should produce the desired output listed at the bottom of this code, but it doesn't. So I tried a couple of other patterns in order to try and get the desired output, but they don't work either. I checked the errata for the book and there are no corrections for this page. I'm using python 2.7.6. Any suggestions?

```
import re

s1 = 'http://www.python.org http://python.org www.python.org python.org .python.org ww.python.org w.python.org wwww.python.org'

# choose a pattern and comment out the other two

# output using Hetland's pattern
pat = r'(http://)?(www\.)?python\.org'
''' [('http://', 'www.'), ('http://', ''), ('', 'www.'), ('', ''), ('', ''), ('', ''), ('', ''), ('', 'www.')] '''

# output using this pattern
# pat = r'http://?www\.?python\.org'
''' ['http://www.python.org'] '''

# output using this pattern
# pat = r'http://?|www\.?|python\.org'
''' ['http://', 'www.', 'python.org', 'www.', 'http://', 'python.org', 'www.', 'python.org', 'python.org', 'python.org', 'python.org', 'python.org', 'www', 'python.org'] '''

print '\n', re.findall(pat, s1)

# desired output
''' ['http://www.python.org', 'http://python.org', 'www.python.org', 'python.org'] '''
```

Comment: If it's a correctly encoded URL you could just split for the given example, but I take it this is for cases where a URL like string may appear anywhere in a block of text?

Comment: I tried split on all three of the patterns and none of them worked, and it would be for a url like string anywhere in a block of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern works if you make the first two optional groups non-capture groups `(?:...)`:

```
pat = r'(?:http://)?(?:www\.)?python\.org'
matches = re.findall(pat, s1)
# ['http://www.python.org', 'http://python.org', 'www.python.org', 'python.org', 'python.org', 'python.org', 'python.org', 'www.python.org']
```

That is, if that's the desired result - as the change to the pattern means there's only one capture group instead of three...

Comment: Using Jon's method you could put the results in a `set` to _filter_ out the duplicates. `print '\n', set(re.findall(pat, s1))`.

Comment: That helps with the desired results if I change the code to this:

`result = re.findall(pat, s1)`
`unique = []`
`for element in result:`
    `if element not in unique:`
        `unique.append(element)`
`print unique`

Comment: @Drewness, basically the same thing that I just added and was working on when you posted your suggestion, except the formatting on my filtering code is all jacked up even though I didn't post it that way.